# Correctly Saving and Updating Entites in Netsjs+TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I've got a Question regarding TypeORM-Relations and how to use them 'nest-like'.

Suppose I have two Entities defined `ChildEntity` and `TestEntity`, which are related.

`TestEntity`:

```js
import { ChildEntity } from 'src/modules/child-entity/entities/child-entity.entity';
import { Column, Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class TestEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => ChildEntity, (childEntity) => childEntity.testEntities)
  childEntity: ChildEntity;

  constructor(name: string, childEntity: ChildEntity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.childEntity = childEntity;
  }
}
```

My first question occurs when I want to create the entity.  I have to first translate the passed `childEntityId` into a `ChildEntity`, which I can pass to the constructor:

`CreateTestEntityDto`

```js
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsNotEmpty, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateTestEntityDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNumber()
  childEntityId: number;

  constructor(name: string, childEntityId: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.childEntityId = childEntityId;
  }
}
```

```js
  async create(createTestEntityDto: CreateTestEntityDto) {
    const { name, childEntityId } = createTestEntityDto;
    const childEntity = await this.childEntityService.findOne(childEntityId);
    const testEntity = new TestEntity(name, childEntity);
    return this.testEntityRepo.save(testEntity);
  }
```

Is there a way to just pass the `childEntityId` to the `save()`-Method without explicitly looking for the `ChildEntity` beforehand?

---

The Second problem occurs when updating.

`UpdateTestEntityDto`

```js
import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { CreateTestEntityDto } from './create-test-entity.dto';

export class UpdateTestEntityDto extends PartialType(CreateTestEntityDto) {}
```

As updating only a partial Entity is possible I have to check if the Id is even passed along the request and if it is I have to retrieve the correct Entity for the update. Is there a more streamlined way to do this?

```js
  async update(id: number, updateTestEntityDto: UpdateTestEntityDto) {
    const { name, childEntityId } = updateTestEntityDto;
    const props = { name };
    if (childEntityId) {
      props['childEntity'] = await this.childEntityService.findOne(
        childEntityId,
      );
    }
    return this.testEntityRepo.update(id, props);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `childEntityId` to the test entity:

```
@Entity()
export class TestEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;

  @Column('int')
  childEntityId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => ChildEntity, (childEntity) => childEntity.testEntities)
  childEntity: ChildEntity;

  ...
}
```

and then you can use it to set the id directly. Something like:

```
async create(dto: Dto) {
    const { name, childEntityId } = dto;

    const entity = new TestEntity();
    entity.name = name;
    entity.childEntityId = childEntityId;

    return this.testEntityRepo.save(entity);
}
```

Check [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/447) out.

Comment: Doesn't this directly oppose one of the principles of TypeORM? TypeORM actually sets the childEntityId on the TestEntity-Table in the Database due to the `ManyToOne` Annotation, but maps this to a ChildEntity-Object in code.

Comment: TypeORM does set the child id but there is nothing wrong with adding it yourself so you can use it. I've added a link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## 1.) Saving relational entity

There's no need to do all these roundtrips cluttering to save the entity. While, the solution given by @UrosAndelic works but still there's no need to write 3 extra lines of code.

If you hover over a relational param inside the `create()` method of the repository from an IDE, you'll notice that it accepts two types. First, An `Instance` of an entity OR Second, a `DeepPartial` object of an entity.

For instance:

```
const entity = this.testEntityRepo.create({
   name: 'Example 1',
   childEntity: {
      id: childEntityId // notice: it's a DeepPartial object of ChildEntity
   }
})

await this.testEntityRepo.save(entity)
```

## 2.) Updating entity

There's no need for child entity's id if you are updating test entity. You can simply update the props of test entity.

```
const testEntityId = 1;

await this.testEntityRepo.update(testEntityId, {
   name: 'Example 2'
})
```

This will update the `name` of `TestEntity = 1`;

Comment: Thanks. For 1) I didn't know this, at the time I was writing my post, but realized it afterwards. 
For 2), My problem exists because I also want to be able to update the `ChildEntity`. But due to the restriction, that I also want to be able to update any partial subset of properties, I run into my problems. But with the knowledge of 1) I'm currently testing a more elegant solution, which I will add here if it works as intended